# What is the best way to store big data per user?

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, database

I just need some advice about what database should I use, and how should I store my data.
Namely I need to store big chunk of data per user, I was thinking about storing everything in JSON data, but I thought that I could ask you first.

So I am using Django, and for now MySql, I need to store like 1000-2000 table rows per user, with columns like First Name, Last Name, Contact info, and also relate it somehow to the user that created that list. Also I need this to be able to efficiently get data from database.

Is there any way of storing this big data per user?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is (a) opinion-based and (b) asks us to find or recommend an off-site resource, both of which are reason enough to close for being off-topic.

Comment: Frankly speaking, a few thousand data rows is "tiny data". Big data on the other hand is the art of storing millions of gigabyte size CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know pandas is a library that works very well for storing data. So maybe look into that and see what file formats are well documented with it.